RAG capabilties - Would it be possible for RAG to answer questions that would require knowledge from the whole (or big part of) corpus of documents?
I have a corpus of text documents (in the thousands) of transcribed one-to-one calls from several departments of a company, including Sales, Support, etc.
I have already iterated through each document, using Llama 3.1 8B with Ollama to read the whole document and had it extract several features from it and return them in a json, some categorical (1 of X possibilities) such as call_type ('Sales', 'Support', 'Personal'), outlook ('Optimistic', 'Pessimistic', 'Neutral'), sweary ('Yes', 'No'), participant names, and some non-categorical (such as summary, title, call_intent, sentiment).
These calls might take hours and can be as much as 20k tokens (although the average is around 4k).
I would be using nomic for embeddings and FAISS as the vector database using Langchain.
I am running Llama 3.1 8B at 24k context but I believe nomic only supports up to 8K tokens, so transcripts larger than that would have to be chunked. I am unsure if appending some of the previously extracted features to every chunk would be useful in relation with the call it belongs to (so that they are also turned into embeddings to help the search) in addition to metadata for filtering.
My question would be, is it possible to ask a RAG to questions such as 'Which sales person had the highest number of sales this month?' (would require all 'Sales' calls of this month to be read) or 'What was the overall sentiment of this month's calls for sales person X?'/'What was the percentage of successful sales to calls for sales person X?' (would require all of this month's calls for sales person X to be read)?  I know we can ask it questions such as 'Give 5 examples of recently successful sales strategies', where a top k > 5 would accommodate it by finding the top 5 most similar (chunks of recently successful sales calls) and reading from those will derive its answer.
I'm unsure if the prior questions are possible using RAG, but if they are not, could a database approach accommodate questions that require counting or pooling information, for example, adding each document in a database with its categorical extracted features and have the LLM decide if this is a question which a small number of highly relevant transcript chunks would answer (to proceed with RAG) or if this is a question that a database query would answer (with .count() ) (to proceed with a database query)?

You have unstructured documents from which you want to query mostly statistical information. RAG alone may not be sufficient for this.
You can use RAG with Structured Outputs to extract relevant structured information from the documents and store the structured outputs in database tables.
You can then write functions that will select from these tables, do mathematical calculations, etc. and use Function Calling so that the LLM will just call the relevant functions for the metrics.
This way the LLM output will be more reliable. You will also be able to extend this approach to query from a CRM if required.
